Unable to implement forms authentication in ASP.NET webforms on .NET 4.8
Here is my web.config:
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.8" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.8" />
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
      </namespaces>
      <controls>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" tagPrefix="webopt" />
      </controls>
    </pages>
    <caching>
      
    </caching>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="logon.aspx" defaultUrl="Default.aspx" />
    </authentication>

    <authorization>
      <deny users="*"/>
    </authorization>
    
</system.web>

The expected output is that logon.aspx should be allowed for anonymous users, but other pages should be accessible only to authenticated users.

You could try the methods mentioned in these two documents Document 1, Document 2

You could refer to the implementation below.
Project structure:

In this project, only the user could access the page of the View folder after logging in, and direct access to MainForm.aspx will be denied and they will navigate to the Login.aspx.
Login.aspx
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            username: <asp:TextBox id="TxtUsername" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            password: <asp:TextBox id="TxtPassword" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:Button  onclick="Submit_Click" runat="server" Text="Submit"/>
        </div>
    </form>

The following code, when the user successfully verifies the account and password, will be authorized to access through cookies.
Login.aspx.cs
    public partial class Login : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var username = TxtUsername.Text;
            var password = TxtPassword.Text;
            if (username =="123" && password =="123") {
    //Note: "admin" must be the same as <allow users="admin">
                var ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, "admin", DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(10), false, "MyRole");


                HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket));
                Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
                Response.Redirect("View/MainForm.aspx");
            }
        }
    }

Web.config
<system.web>
     <authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="Login.aspx" name="LoginCookieName" defaultUrl="View/MainForm.aspx">
  </forms>
     </authentication>
      …
</system.web>
<location path="Login.aspx">
         <system.web>
    <authorization>
        <allow users ="*" />
    </authorization>
        </system.web>
</location>
<location path="View">
         <system.web>
     <authorization >
        <allow users="admin"></allow>
        <deny users ="?" />
        <deny users="*"/>
    </authorization>
         </system.web>
</location>


@Shaharukh Pathan, May I know if you have got any chance to check my answer?
